# A list with different items on each view-list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, item

I try to configure in MS Sharepoint a list with about 20 items. It works so on.
Example:
First Name,
Name,
Phone,
Office,
Acronym,
etc.

Now I would like to set up the list for about 3 teams/persons.

Team 1: When team 1/or Person1 wants to create a new item, they can only see First Name, Name and acronym.

Team 2: When team 2/or Person2 wants to create a new item, they can only see First Name, Name, and Office.

Team 3: When team 3/or Person3 wants to create a new item, they can see the whole list.

It doesn't work with different views. I thought it is easier to send them E-Mails with different views. So I send different links with the individual views and they the in the beginning the items I've listed above but if they add a new item, they see the whole list. (The different teams/users are created by me, so I can test all day long)

Does anyone have a solution for this issue? I searched hours but I didn't found anything...

Answer (score 0):

(1) You have to give **column level permissions**. There are some third party tools available for column level permissions:

- [Column Level Security](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx)
- [SharePoint Column/View Permission](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission-business-scenario.html#CVP-1)

(2) You can create **Custom NewForm Webpart**

- Custom Webpart will hide/show appropriate column texts(controls) as per user permissions.
- Create 3 SP Groups `Team1`, `Team2`, `Team3`
- Write code to check the users in groups and display controls on webpart as per the group.
- Replace this new custom webpart with existing list NewForm.aspx with this webpart. So, whenever you click on list `new item` button, it will open this custom webpart rather than default new form.
- Write following code on `FeatureActivated` or where ever you want to change list's default new form. Here is the code which will run on `FeatureActivated`:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPWeb currentWeb = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
            try
            {
            //listname1 = YourListName
            SPLimitedWebPartManager NewForm = currentWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Lists/listname1/NewForm.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            AddWebPart(NewForm);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
          }
protected void AddWebPart(SPLimitedWebPartManager MainPage)
    {
        MainPage.WebParts[0].Hidden = true;
        MainPage.SaveChanges(MainPage.WebParts[0]);
        try
        {
            var linqqry = from wp in MainPage.WebParts.Cast()
                          where wp.GetType() == typeof(Webpart1.Webpart1)
                          select wp;

        if (linqqry.Count() == 0)
        {
            //Create an instance of WPMenu Webpart and add in a Webpart zone
            Webpart1.Webpart1 wpWebPart = new Webpart1.Webpart1();
            MainPage.AddWebPart(wpWebPart, "Main", 0);
            MainPage.SaveChanges(wpWebPart);
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this and I will update you soon again.